# Exception while launching spark using spark-shell: error: not found: value spark

Tags: linux, apache-spark

I started learning recently. So I downloaded Oracle Virtual Box and HDFS cluster from cloudera. It is Linux centos. When I launched spark for the first time, it had the version 1.6.0 by default. Hence I downloaded spark version 2.2.0 and pointed the spark home to it. From then I get spark 2.2.0 by default. But when I launch it using spark-shell, it says error: not found: value spark.
The whole exception tree can be seen below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/07/08 04:06:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
18/07/08 04:06:09 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
  at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

I tried to fix it by looking at similar reference online but the issue keeps re-occuring. Could anyone tell me how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. It seems to be a problem with IP/ Host resolution. you need to follow exactly what stack is telling you.

In your spark conf set `spark.driver.bindAddress = <your ip>`

you can find your ip by `ifconfig` or `ip addr` command